# Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am trying apply this function on a data frame to create a new feature but I keep getting this error:

> Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : object 'INSTALLMENT' of mode 'function' was not found

I have also tried `apply(df, 2, purchase)` but then I get this error:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

The code is :

```
purchase = function(DataFrame){

  if((DataFrame$ONEOFF_PURCHASES == 0) && (DataFrame$INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES == 0))
    return('NONE')

  if((DataFrame$ONEOFF_PURCHASES > 0) && (DataFrame$INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES > 0))
    return('BOTH_ONEOFF_INSTALLMENT')

  if((DataFrame$ONEOFF_PURCHASES > 0) && (DataFrame$INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES == 0))
    return('ONE_OFF')

  if((DataFrame$ONEOFF_PURCHASES == 0) && (DataFrame$INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES > 0))
    return('INSTALLMENT')
}

df$PURCHASE_TYPE = apply(df, 2, purchase(df))
```

Comment: That's not how you use `apply`- try `apply(df, 2, purchase)`

Comment: I have already tried that. I get this error then :
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a `ifelse()` case. `if() ... else ...` can only treat a single boolean. To make your function work, you need to vectorize it by `mapply()` or `Vectorize()`.

**Example Data**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(ONEOFF_PURCHASES = sample(0:1, 5, T), INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES = sample(0:1, 5, T))

#   ONEOFF_PURCHASES INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES
# 1                0                      0
# 2                1                      0
# 3                0                      0
# 4                0                      1
# 5                1                      1
```

**Function**

```
purchase <- function(x, y){
  if((x == 0) && (y == 0))
    return('NONE')
  else if((x > 0) && (y > 0))
    return('BOTH_ONEOFF_INSTALLMENT')
  else if((x > 0) && (y == 0))
    return('ONE_OFF')
  else if((x == 0) && (y > 0))
    return('INSTALLMENT')
  else
    return('OTHERS')
}
```

**Vectorization**

```
mapply(purchase, df$ONEOFF_PURCHASES, df$INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES)
# [1] "NONE"  "ONE_OFF"  "NONE"  "INSTALLMENT"  "BOTH_ONEOFF_INSTALLMENT"

Vectorize(purchase)(df$ONEOFF_PURCHASES, df$INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES)
# [1] "NONE"  "ONE_OFF"  "NONE"  "INSTALLMENT"  "BOTH_ONEOFF_INSTALLMENT"
```

---

Actually, we don't use the approach above in this issue. We'll use `ifelse()` or `dplyr::case_when()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(PURCHASE_TYPE = case_when(
    (ONEOFF_PURCHASES == 0) & (INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES == 0) ~ 'NONE',
    (ONEOFF_PURCHASES > 0) & (INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES > 0) ~ 'BOTH_ONEOFF_INSTALLMENT',
    (ONEOFF_PURCHASES > 0) & (INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES == 0) ~ 'ONE_OFF',
    (ONEOFF_PURCHASES == 0) & (INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES > 0) ~ 'INSTALLMENT',
    TRUE ~ 'OTHERS'
  ))

#   ONEOFF_PURCHASES INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES           PURCHASE_TYPE
# 1                0                      0                    NONE
# 2                1                      0                 ONE_OFF
# 3                0                      0                    NONE
# 4                0                      1             INSTALLMENT
# 5                1                      1 BOTH_ONEOFF_INSTALLMENT
```